# In Django 1.11 getting Circular Import Errors When including app URLconf files in project URLconf File

Tags: django, django-urls, urlconf

I'm new to Django, have been doing several tutorials to get really comfortable with the structuring, and am now running through the official tutorial.

I've created an `polls` App, which has a `polls/views.py` file as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, World. You're at the polls index.")
```

I've also created an App URLconf file `polls/urls.py` with the following code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

url_patterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

This is pretty much exactly as done in the Django tutorial.

My issue is when I'm specifying url routes in the main `projectname/url.py` file on a project level as such:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

When doing this, I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'polls.urls' from 'ProjectFolder\\polls\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

This is how the official Django tutorial dictates it to be done. However, if I explicity import the `polls/views.py` file from the app, I can accomplish the task as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from polls import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', views.index),

]
```

My immediate concern is the import of every app/urls file I ever create being necessitated by this approach, as well as the obvious divergence from the official Django instruction.

I hesitated to even ask this question because I feel that such a fundamental issue has bound to have an easy fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To clarify, I can get around the error by explicitly importing the view files from apps. Whenever using the Django documentation-described approach of using the `include()` function I receive the error. I can appreciate the value of this function, and would like to know *why* is giving me the error described above.

Comment: The `polls/views.py` file is the first block of code in my question.

Comment: can you try to do ```from polls.views import index```. I think there's a conflict as you import views in the two files.

Comment: Yes, reference the second block of code in my question.

Comment: yes sorry i've updated my comment, i didn't see it at first

Comment: Made an answer, i think your error is about naming the pattern. See below

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just writte `urlpatterns = [ ..` and not `url_patterns` in your `poll.views.py`.

Comment: the `url_patterns` list is explained by the Django documentation as belonging in the `poll.urls.py` file, just as it belongs in the `mainprojectname/urls.py` file. Even if you are referring to the `urls.py` files, I'm still not sure what you are describing.

Comment: can you link me that tutorial? From the official document i see : ```urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]``` and not ```url_patterns``` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view

Comment: I'm just saying you misspelled the variable name ```urlpatterns```

Comment: No problem, that happens sometime :)